# list comprehension to check for True values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame and a List. Every Item of the DataFrame that doesn't match with the Item in the List should be set to None. I wrote a list comprehension which should check if that the item is not in the list is True and in this case should set the item of the DataFrame to None.
Can someone Explain me why I get a ValueError. I tried the methods recommended from the ValueError but they didn't work.

My Code:

```
abc = ['A', 'B', 'C']
l = ['A', 'B', 'None', '5-20', 'C', '200-500', 'D', '1000', 'A']
l = pd.DataFrame(l)

[None for i in l if ~l[i].isin(abc) == True]
       
print(l)
```

Output:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

Expected Result:

```
      0
0     A
1     B
2  None
3  None
4     C
5  None
6  None
7  None
8     A
```

Comment: Can you post the expected result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) with boolean indexing

```
l[~l.isin(abc)] = None
l
      0
0     A
1     B
2  None
3  None
4     C
5  None
6  None
7  None
8     A
```

---

`isin` will return `True` if item contains in given sequence `abc` for each row of dataframe `l`.

```
l.isin(abc)
       0
0   True
1   True
2  False
3  False
4   True
5  False
6  False
7  False
8   True
```

Here, we want to set `None` where value is `False` (where value does not match to list) so we will inverse it using Bitwise (`~`) so we can use it for boolean indexing later.

```
~l.isin(abc)
       0
0  False
1  False
2   True
3   True
4  False
5   True
6   True
7   True
8  False
```

And then simply set to `None` using [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

```
l[~l.isin(abc)] = None
l
      0
0     A
1     B
2  None
3  None
4     C
5  None
6  None
7  None
8     A
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer it worked best for me. Can you give a short explanation how that works? Does this way of indexing only work with boolean?

Comment: @Changer I have updated my answer with some explanation. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) for set to `None` if no match:

```
a = l.where(l.isin(abc), None)
       
print(a)
      0
0     A
1     B
2  None
3  None
4     C
5  None
6  None
7  None
8     A
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) method like this:

```
>>> print(l.mask(~l.isin(abc), None))
      0
0     A
1     B
2  None
3  None
4     C
5  None
6  None
7  None
8     A
```